# Using SwiftyJSON, array cannot assign value of type AnyObject to type String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have this variable:

```
var fetchedImagesArray: [String] = []
```

Then I fetch an array of images name from my server using Alamofire and SwiftyJson like this:

```
if let fetchedImages = json["images"].arrayObject {

fetchedImagesArray = fetchedImages

}
```

But I get the error here **fetchedImagesArray = fetchedImages** saying: cannot assign value of type anyobject to type string.

The array returned loooks like this ["imgName1","imgName2","imgName3"] which is all strings to why cant I set fetchedImagesArray?

Comment: Have you tried `if let fetchedImages = json["images"].arrayObject as [String]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SwiftJSON` the property `arrayObject` returns `[AnyObject]?` so you have to downcast the array to its actual type

```
if let fetchedImages = json["images"].arrayObject as? [String] {
    fetchedImagesArray = fetchedImages
}
```